# How can I size the marker (square) to let its scale value be its actual area?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I want to have a square for each administrative area.

A value tells its area in reality.

For each administrative area the square should be as big as in reality.

So if I zoom in and out it should not change in size.

If I measure the width of the square using the scale of the map, and take it to the square (^2), I end up with the area value used at the beginning.

[Proportional Circles](https://github.com/LCacheux68224/ProportionalCircles) may be related to what I try to accomplish, however I need a square, not a circle.

Comment: I am a little confused by your request. If you are displaying a map of polygons than a marker symbol should not be necessary. Can you please explain your data more as in are you trying to make a map of Point, line or polygon data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be doable as long as your polygons have a cartesian coordinate system (not Lat-long).

Change the style to a single symbol, centroid fill, simple marker. Set the Size to 1, the units to "Map Units" and click the expression button and Edit... and set the value to "sqrt($area)".

Choose a square symbol from the list above "Layer Rendering". It should look a bit like this:

[image]

That gives me the pink squares here:

[image]

The underlying polygons are in another layer, and also shown. They look about the right size.

Comment: can also use the **size assistant** with the **surface** option, which will work for squares *and* circles - but your method is much simpler :)